# Counting numbers and letters

Tags: java

I have to write a program that has to read a set of 13 cards in a  String with inputs like C3567JD798S4H687 (C standing for Clubs, D for Diamonds, S for Spades, H for Hearts) and the output needs to separate each suit on a different line so on one line you will have C3567J and on the next you would have D798 etc.

I am not very sure on how to have the program recognize the end of a suit like when to start a new count once it reads a D or S.

So far I have only figured out how to separate letters and numbers which I had thought would be the first step.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.* ;
public class Cards  
{

   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException 
   {
        BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));


    System.out.print("Enter cards:");
    String cards = objReader.readLine ();

          Test obj = new Test (cards);
          String gC = obj.GetCards();
          String gN = obj.GetNumber();

   System.out.println("Letters" + suitC);
   System.out.println("Numbers" + numbers);
   }
}
class Test 
   {
     private String suitC = "";
     private String numbers = "";

     Test (String sC, String n)
     {
       suitC = sC;
       numbers = n;
     }
     private void Separation(String s)
     {
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
      {
        char a = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(a)) 
        {
          suitC = suitC + a;
        } 
        else 
        {
          numbers = numbers + a;
        }
      }
     }

     String GetSuitC()
     {
         return suitC;
     }
     String GetNumber()
     {
      return numbers; 
     }
   }
```

Comment: Your post lacks any concrete question.

Comment: It does not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily have to separate numbers and letters. Treat the whole thing as 1 string. Try to search for the suit letter, then print the substring until that point. Now the next substring starts where the last one ended.